# android contacts unformatted and formatted number

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number, invisible

Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge, Android 6.0.1, Microsoft Exchange Active Sync.

In my app I enumerate all phone numbers for a person. For some people the mobile phone number is listed twice, one with the (manual) formatting I use when I enter the number in Outlook and one with all formatting removed.

Entered and displayed correctly: 010-123 45 67
Also for some people my app gets: 0101234567. 
This is what is displayed if I send an SMS to that person and Android seems to remember that number and save it invisibly in the address book.

If I look up the person in both Outlook Contacts and on the phone contacts, only the formatted number is visible.

Any clue how to remove the unformatted numbers?

Comment: That link didn't work

Comment: A Quick and Dirty solution:
String stripped = stripSeparators(phoneNumber);
    if (stripped.equals(phoneNumber) == false)
           theNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
However there must be a better way because there might be unformatted numbers in my address book and if so, they will be excluded.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it although I'm sure there is a better way.

```
phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
String stripped = stripSeparators(phoneNumber);
int count = theNumbers.size();
boolean present = false;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
  if (stripSeparators(theNumbers.get(i)).equals(stripped) == true)
  {
    present = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (present == false)
  theNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
```

Comment: This does only work if the numbers come in a certain order. I've solved it by first collecting all numbers and then search for duplicates. Not pretty.